# Question about plotting indifference curves

Tags: functions, economics

So I am doing a last year paper on microeconomics and I'm asked to find pareto efficiencies, cores and so on within the edgeworth box. So what I want to know is that when they give me in this exercise the consumer 1 utility as $xy$, how do I plot this $xy$ within the edgeworth box?
I want to know its shape, and the same goes for all cobbdouglas functions… the only additional information given that I think is useful is total endowment and initial endowment.

Answer (score 1):

$$U(x,y)=x\cdot y\Rightarrow U(x,y)=c\Rightarrow x\cdot y(x)=c\Rightarrow y(x)=\dfrac{c}{x}$$

Comment: What is c? cheers!

Comment: c is the constant value of the utility in one indifference curve